# php same code not returning value

Tags: php, html, mysqli

my php code not executing correctly , i am echoing a category and it is echoing perfectly but when i am freeing my variable i am getting error saying  mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given ....

```
<li><a href="#" > <?php while($result3 = mysqli_fetch_array($row2)){ 
echo $result3['category'] ; } ?> </a></li>
<?php mysqli_free_result($result3) ; ?>
```

and aditionally none of my php code below this is exectuing , its just returning no data (page source is giving no data )

what mistake am i doing ?

Comment: you should free the $row2

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
<?php mysqli_free_result($result3) ; ?>
```

do this

```
<?php mysqli_free_result($row2) ; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqli_result should be the variable you are using to store the query. IE:

`$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

You'd want to

```
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

By the looks of your code, you should free $row2

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra statement from code and add it inside the loop

```
<li><a href="#" > 
  <?php while($result3 = mysqli_fetch_array($row2)){ 
       echo $result3['category'] ; 
       mysqli_free_result($row2) ;
   } ?> </a></li>
```